# Leaflet toggle buttons only work on the first click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a button that I want to use to toggle a map layer on and off. Click once and the layer adds to the map, click again and it goes away (and so on). Right now my button only works on the first click and none thereafter.

I think this has to do with the fact that it's written as an if/else statement. A condition is satisfied, the function ends, and that's the end of it.

Looking for guidance... How do I modify my code to make this a functional toggle button?

My button:

```
<button id="buttonA" onclick=="onoff();">Button A</button>
```

Then, within a function `$.getJSON("mydata.json", function(data) {...});` I have the following:

```
function onoff(){
  currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
}   


document.getElementById("buttonA").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (currentvalue = "Off"){
       LayerA.addTo(map);
       document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
     }
     else{
       map.removeLayer(LayerA); 
       document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (currentvalue = "Off")` to `if (currentvalue == "Off")`

EDITED:
Try in this way:

Button:

```
<button id="buttonA" onclick="onoff();">Button A</button>
```

and js:

```
function onoff(){
      currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;

      if (currentvalue == "Off"){
        LayerA.addTo(map);
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
      }
      else{
        map.removeLayer(LayerA); 
        document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Good catch (I corrected above)! Unfortunately I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Still didn't work for me (I'm not sure why, this seemed like a good fix). I found a solution, though: `document.getElementById("buttonA").addEventListener("click", function(){
        
        if( map.hasLayer(LayerA)){
            map.removeLayer(LayerA);
        }
        else
            {
                LayerA.addTo(map);  
            }
    });` Turns out the Leaflet library has a function `hasLayer` which checks if the map has a particular layer. Thanks.